# calculating $\mathbb{P}(B)$

Tags: probability, statistics

There are six female and four male mice in a group of 10. One of the female
mice and two of the male mice have a particular disease. Suppose that two mice are selected at random from the group without replacement. The following events are defined:

A: Both mice are female.

B: Exactly one of the mice has the disease.

> Question: Compute $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$.

I know $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is $\dfrac{ \binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}$ but why is that?

Comment: These are both examples of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  "*I know $P(B)$ is $\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{1}/\binom{10}{2}$ but why is that?*"  Because there are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to select one mouse with the disease, $\binom{7}{1}$ ways to select the remaining healthy mouse, making the product of these the number of ways of selecting two mice where one is healthy and then we divide by $\binom{10}{2}$ which is the number of ways of selecting two mice to get the probability...

Answer (score 2):

The probability of an event $ = \frac{\text{total number of ways the event can occur}}{\text{total number of outcomes}}$, as long as each outcome is equally likely to occur. Since we are equally likely to choose each mouse,  $$P(B) = \frac{\text{number of ways that exactly one of the chosen mice has the disease}}{\text{number of ways that we can choose two mice}}$$

In order to determine the value of $P(B)$, we simply need to know the value of the numerator and of the denominator.

Numerator = number of ways that exactly one of the chosen mice has the disease

$\hspace{2.1cm}$= number of ways to choose one mouse with the disease $\times$ number of ways to choose one mouse 
$\hspace{2.5cm}$without the disease

$\hspace{2.1cm}$= ${3 \choose 1} \times {7 \choose 1}$ since 2 + 1 = 3 mice have the disease and 10 - 3 = 7 mice do not have the disease

Denominator = number of ways that we can choose two mice

$\hspace{2.1cm}$= ${10 \choose 2}$ since we want to choose 2 mice out of the 10

Hence, $P(B) = \frac{{3 \choose 1} \times {7 \choose 1}}{{10 \choose 2}}$

Comment: Your first line "the probability of an event = ... " needs the qualification that this formula can be used *only* when we know the outcomes to be equally likely to occur.

Comment: Thank you, JMoravitz! I just made that edit